# How do I loop over the months of the year and print them in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
year = int(input("Enter number of years: "))
total = 0

for x in range(year):
for y in range(1,13):
    print("Year {0}".format(x+1))
    precipitation = int(input("Enter precipitation for month {0} mm: ".format(y)))

    total = total + precipitation


totalmonths = year * 12
average = total/totalmonths
print("")
```

Ok how do i loop it so instead of month 1 , 2 ,3 its January , February etc.

Comment: A nice thing about either of the techniques in Tim's answer is that they are locale-aware, so (for example) if you do `import locale` `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.utf8')` before building the month name list, the names will be in Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this:

```
# fill a tuple with the month's names
for y in ('January', 'February', etc):
    # do something
```

Alternatively, create a tuple whose indexes map months' numbers to names, starting at index `1` (I'm filling the first position with `None` because the index `0` won't be used):

```
months = (None, 'January', 'February', etc)
for y in range(1, 13):
    m = months[y] # `m` holds the month's name
```

Notice that I'm using tuples and not lists because month names are unlikely to change. And although we *could* use a `dict` that maps month numbers to names, that would be overkill for this simple case.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks your method works, i never thought loops can have strings in them, i thought it was always numbers.

Comment: @user3373402 loops can iterate over any utterable object, in particular here we're traversing a tuple of strings.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I think "utterable" is a particularly funny typo here.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
import datetime

months = [datetime.date(2000, m, 1).strftime('%B') for m in range(1, 13)]
for month in months:
  print month
```

Alternatively, something like this would also work:

```
import calendar

for i in range(1, 13):
  print calendar.month_name[i]
```